# Are sequentially issued stores/loads completed in the same order?

Tags: c, concurrency

I've been having a huge headache debugging and fixing some parallel execution bugs.

My main issue is that some shared variables in RAM memory are not coherent between processes. Let's say that I have two variables a and b updated as such:

```
a = 5;
b = 10;
```

If I prevent the compiler AND hardware from reordering these two stores, is it always true that other processes will never see a value of 10 in `b` without also seeing a value of 5 in `a`?

Comment: I think you need a memory barrier/fence in between the statements to guarantee that.

Comment: If you mark `a` and `b` as volatile, then [there shouldn't be any problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier#cite_ref-2).

Comment: iff you can prevent compiler and hardware from re-ordering (which seems to be problematic), and assuming that they are written by the same thread, you should see 'a' as 5 iff 'b' is 10.

Answer (score 0):

> If I prevent the compiler AND hardware from reordering these two stores, is it always true that other processes will never see a value of 10 in `b` without also seeing a value of 5 in `a`?

*If you prevent the compiler AND hardware from reordering these two stores* then by definition yes.

But, good luck with that. Just use a mutex, and your life will be much easier.

Comment: The question and in turn this answer ignore the *loads* made the “other processes”  to inspect `a` and `b`, which must be forced to be in order, to be really safe. Though, processes usually have isolated address spaces, which leads to the assumption that the OP’s problem is an entirely different one.